# string extraction after last matching char using SSRS expression

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have on string as `"*Path\Release1.0\Iteration1.0*"`. I want to extract string after last occurrence of backlash character `\` which means I should get `"*Iteration1.0*"` as result here.

How should I write my expression in SSRS to get desired output? 
I have written expression as follows but it is not giving result as expected:

```
=Mid(Fields!IterationPath.Value, 1 + InStr(3, Fields!IterationPath.Value, "\"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
=Mid(Fields!IterationPath.Value, InStrRev(Fields!IterationPath.Value, "\") + 1)
```